# Random 6 to 10 digits number

Tags: scala, random

I am generating a random numerical 6-10 digit password. I need some important reviews of yours.  Is it OK or are there some needed modifications?

```
val AB = "0123456789669900"
val rnd = new Random()

def randomNumericalString(): String = {
    val len = rnd.nextInt(5) + 5
    val sb = new StringBuilder(len)
    for (i <- 0 to len)
      sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())))
    return sb.toString
  }
```

Comment: Does it have to be numerical? For safety issue's I don't recommand that(bruteforce on int pw's goes very fast). If not => scala has also : `nextString(length: Int)`

Comment: my bad luck,yes it have to be numerical

Comment: Why on earth is it important that 6,9, and 0 appear three times more often than other digits in the generated passwords?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca just like that ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm makes the probabilities of some numbers much higher than other numbers. Is this intentional? For example, 0 will appear 3 times as often as 1. It would be better to simply have the input string `"0123456789"` and have the uniform distribution.

The range you supply in your for-loop is confusing, the requirements are for 6 digits, but, you use the magic-number 5. in the random. Consider using:

```
val shortest = 6
val longest = 10
val len = shortest + rnd.nextInt(longest - shortest + 1)
for (i <- 1 to len)
```

That is enough of an answer, on it's own, but I would suggest you consider the following. It is a little flawed in the sense that it never generates a value with a 0 as the first character.... I was part way through the answer when I realized this, but thought you should consider the approach anyway:

```
def randomNumericalString(): String = {
    return ((100000.0 + rnd.nextDouble() * (10000000000.0 - 100000.0)).toLong).toString
}
```

The above will generate a random number, with uniform distribution, between 100000 and 9999999999 (and [here, as an ideone](http://ideone.com/HXe1Wc) )

Answer (score 4):

While your function is not incorrect, there is some ambiguity in the specification, and I would have interpreted it differently.  The question is, what constitutes a random PIN of 6 to 10 digits?

What you have done is choose the length, such that lengths 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 are equally probable.

However, there are approximately 10 times more 7-digit PINs than there are 6-digit PINs, and 10 times more 8-digit PINs than there are 7-digit PINs.  If you were to enumerate all possible PINs from 000000 to 9999999999, then take a uniform sample, you would end up with a much different distribution of results, tending heavily towards the longer PINs.  By my interpretation, this kind of uniform sampling would be implied if no probability distribution is specified.

To be more exact, there is 1 PIN of length 0 (namely `""`), 10 PINs of length 1 (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5,`6, `7`, `8`, `9`), 100 PINs of length 2, etc.

$$\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n & \textrm{Number of PINs of length }n & \textrm{Number of PINs of length }\le n \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 10 & 11 \\
2 & 100 & 111 \\
3 & 1000 & 1111 \\
4 & 10000 & 11111 \\
\vdots
\end{array}$$

Therefore, by my interpretation, if the PINs are to range from 6 to 10 digits, there should be a \$\frac{10}{111110}\$ probability of terminating after generating 6 digits, \$\frac{100}{111110}\$ probability of terminating after 7 digits, \$\frac{1000}{111110}\$ probability of terminating after 8 digits, \$\frac{10000}{111110}\$ probability of terminating after 9 digits, and \$\frac{100000}{111110}\$ probability of terminating after 10 digits.

Here is an implementation that produces such a distribution of lengths:

```
val digits = "0123456789669900"
val rnd = new Random()

def randomPIN(minLen:Int=6, maxLen:Int=10): String = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder(maxLen)
    def appendRandomDigit() = {
        sb.append(digits.charAt(rnd.nextInt(digits.length())))
    }

    for (i <- 0 until minLen)
        appendRandomDigit

    var possibleOptionalStrings = 0 to (maxLen - minLen) reduce {
        (a, _) => 10 * a + 1
    }
    while (rnd.nextDouble >= 1.0 / possibleOptionalStrings) {
        appendRandomDigit
        possibleOptionalStrings = (possibleOptionalStrings - 1) / 10
    }

    return sb.toString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can understand the possible need for a numeric-only password, for example, if it needs to be entered using a numeric keypad.  Typically, a numeric-only password is called a PIN, and I recommend using that terminology.  PINs carry less entropy than an alphanumeric password, but they can still be secure if the system takes measures to prevent brute-force attacks.  I cannot fathom the desire to bias the probabilities towards digits 6, 9, and 0, though.  I'm sure you are equally puzzled, and I won't question that weird requirement.

Some quick observations:

- `AB` is a weird name.  How about `digits` instead?
- `for (i <- 0 to n) …` is awkward and will likely lead to off-by-one errors.  Logical ways to write a for-loop that repeats *n* times are:

  ```
  for (i <- 0 until n) …
  ```

  or

  ```
  for (i <- 1 to n) …
  ```

  I suggest

  ```
  for (_ <- 0 until len) {
      sb.append(digits.charAt(rnd.nextInt(digits.length())))
  }
  ```

  since

  - You don't actually care about the value of `i`
  - It's bad practice to omit the optional braces
- Scala allows default parameter values.  Therefore, you can get additional flexibility and clarity for "free".

Rewriting…

```
val digits = "0123456789669900"
val rnd = new Random()

def randomPIN(minLen:Int=6, maxLen:Int=10): String = {
    val len = rnd.nextInt(1 + maxLen - minLen) + minLen
    val sb = new StringBuilder(len)
    for (_ <- 0 until len) {
        sb.append(digits.charAt(rnd.nextInt(digits.length())))
    }
    return sb.toString
}
```